# multer req.files.filename is always undefined

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, multer

Trying to upload a file with Angular nodejs express mongodb using multer
the row gets added and the file appears into the 'uploads' folder but req.files.filename returns undefined

here is my api.js

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, callBack) => {
        -callBack(null, "./uploads/");
        +callBack(null, "uploads/")
    },
    filename: (req, file, callBack) => {
        const name = file.originalname
        callBack(null, name); 
    }
})

router.post('/create',multer({ storage : storage}).any(), (req, res) => {
    const url = req.protocol + '://'+ req.get("host");  
    var tc = new Testcase({
        name: req.body.name,
        upload: url + "/uploads/" + req.files.filename ,
        run: req.body.run,
        modify: req.body.modify,
        delete: req.body.delete,
        step1: req.body.step1,
        step2: req.body.step2,
        step3: req.body.step3,
        step4: req.body.step4,
        step5: req.body.step5,
        step6: req.body.step6,
        step7: req.body.step7,
    });
    
    console.log(req.files.filename);
    tc.save((err, doc) => {
        if (err) { res.status(401).send("error") }
        else { 
            res.status(200).send(doc)
        }
    });
});
```

My api.service.ts

```
 private create = 'http://localhost:5555/testcase/create';

postTestCase(testcase,file:File) {
   const formData  = new FormData();
   formData .append('file', file);
   formData .append('name', testcase.name);
   formData .append('step1', testcase.step1);
   formData .append('modify', testcase.modify);
   formData .append('run', testcase.run);
   formData .append('delete', testcase.delete);
   formData .append('step2', testcase.step2);
   formData .append('step3', testcase.step3);
   formData .append('step4', testcase.step4);
   formData .append('step5', testcase.step5);
   formData .append('step6', testcase.step6);
   formData .append('step7', testcase.step7);

   return this.http.post<any>(this.create, formData   );
 }
```

this is the component.ts code:

```
addtestcaseData = {'name': '',
  'step1': '',
  
  'modify': '',
  'run': '',
  'delete': '',
  'upload': File = null,
  'step2': '',
  'step3': '',
  'step4': '',
  'step5': '',
  'step6': '',
  'step7':''}

addtestcase(){
    this.testcaseService.postTestCase(this.addtestcaseData,this.addtestcaseData.upload)
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res)
        this._router.navigate(['/admin'])
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
        
        
      }
    )     
  };
```

For the html i added (enctype="multipart/form-data") to the form aswell but still no luck

Comment: see [multer npm any()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#any), it will return array of files in `req.files`, you can access by `req.files[0].filename`

Answer (score 0):

your req.files is an array
you can loop through it and extract them like:

```
   let fileNames = []
    req.files.forEach((file)=> {
       fileName.push(file.fileName)
    }
```

then you can save this array as your post images in mongodb